# Next letters as against a char variable

Tags: c#, wpf, char

I have a `char` variable *c* and a `TextBox` *textbox1* in my C# application. I want to do this:

```
textbox1.Text = (c + 2).ToString(); //this doesn't work, sure
```

For example:

```
c = 'b';
textbox1.Text = "d";
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
textbox1.Text = ((char)(((int)c) + 2)).ToString();
```

Comment: Now its good, but one pare of parenthese are too much. See my example.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why everyone's casting to int...

```
textbox1.Text = ((char)(c + 2)).ToString();
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this -

```
textbox1.Text = Convert.ToChar((int)c +2).ToString()
```

Comment: Oh i just missed it converting back to char. My bad. Anywyas that would have given you 102 and not 53. Though, updated my answer. Completely missed it casting back to char.. :)